# Sort attributes (HTML/Vue) on VSCode breaking self-close tags

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, posthtml

I am currently using `Sorting HTML and Jade attributes` extension on VS Code to auto-sort my Vue attributes. I set it up so that it will be executed when saving.

**My problem:**
When executing, my self-closed Vue components are changed.

ex.

Let's say this is my code:

```
<div>
  <MyComponent />
  <div>
    Some text inside second div
  </div>
</div
```

It is then translated to:

```
<div>
  <MyComponent>
     <div>
       Some text inside second div
     </div>
  </MyComponent>
</div
```

And this breaks the application!

Any idea how to get around with this??

Thank you so much!